Will the MongoDB: "4.7.0" npm is compatible for nodev20 in the Azure functions for cosmosDB version 4.2?
We are planning to upgrade Nodejs version from v18.x to v20.x.
Our application is cloud application, and we are using Azure CosmosDB with MongoDB API.
Currently MongoDB Driver version is 4.7.0.
My question is, will the MongoDB: "4.7.0" npm be compatible for Nodejs v20 in the Azure functions for CosmosDB version 4.2 with MongoDB API?

As per official documentation Node.js v20.x.x will not be compatible with lower than 5.6.x versions.
You can refer the link: MongoDB Compatibility 


SONIA_29, Thank you so much for your reply.
